# How to Create a Root-Level Dynamic Route Like article-:title in Nuxt.js 2?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, dynamic-routing

I'm building a Nuxt.js 2 application and want to implement a root-level dynamic route with a format like article-:title. The :title portion would be dynamic and based on the article's title. I'm aiming for URLs like `/article-my-article-title`.

I attempted to create a file named `article-_title.vue` within the pages directory. Here's what's inside that file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Article: {{ title }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    const title = params.title;
    return { title };
  }
}
</script>
```

However, I'm running into issues where the route does not seem to be recognized. I get a "Page not found" error.

Has anyone successfully implemented a similar pattern in Nuxt.js 2? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you should name the file like `_article-title.vue`